# Angular implementing a status thread which accesses a webservice

Tags: angular

Im new to Angular and still not 100% on this whole subscription/observables thing.

I have a webservice which when called will return a status object that my site is interested in. The way the webservice is set up, it will hold the connection open for 30 seconds and if there is nothing new to report will close the connection, at which point I should resubmit my request for status and so on. This way there is always a connection to the webservice.

How do I do this in angular? I need to make a Service that will constantly ping this webservice for status but the normal HTTP Client observable is a one and done observable. And Im not even entirely sure how to set up an asynchronous thread.

The status endpoint will return a status object which could contain new data to display on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Observable.interval`:

```
class SomeService {
  public statusPing$: Observable;

  constructor(private http: HttpService) {
    this.statusPing = Observable.interval(30000)
      .switchMap(http.get('/api/ping/your_slug'))
  }
}
```

Things to note:

1. You need to import the `interval` operator (I listed only the relevant code).
2. You might want to further map the response (`(respones) => response.json()`)
3. You must make the observable hot, meaning, somewhere in your code do `svc.statusPing$.subscribe()`.

Comment: @Meir FYI you wrote to use `Observable.interval` but in your example you're using `Observable.timer`.